# Hide individual pointer cursor (because of flicker) in KDE in dual pointer setup with touchscreen

Tags: x11, kde, xinput, cursor, xcursor

Under Kubuntu 17.04, I'm trying to obtain a dual pointer setup where one is attached to my mouse as usual and the other is attached to the touchscreen that otherwise works correctly while attached to the core pointer (including pinch-like gestures):

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ My touchscreen                            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ My mouse                                  id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
...
```

Following [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129353/235491), I created another pointer and attached the touchscreen to it:

```
$ xinput create-master Touchscreen
$ xinput reattach 11 "Touchscreen pointer"
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ My mouse                                  id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
...
⎡ Touchscreen pointer                           id=21   [master pointer  (22)]
⎜   ↳ My touchscreen                            id=11   [slave  pointer  (21)]
⎜   ↳ Touchscreen XTEST pointer                 id=23   [slave  pointer  (21)]
⎣ Touchscreen keyboard                          id=22   [master keyboard (21)]
    ↳ Touchscreen XTEST keyboard                id=24   [slave  keyboard (22)]
```

This is also functional, including gestures. The problem is the cursor attached to the Touchscreen pointer flickers. This does not happen with the core pointer. What is weird is that the flicker only happens when the I move the mouse pointer. If I don't move the mouse, the Touchscreen pointer stays invisible when the touchscreen is not used, which is very close to what I want. **Ideally, the touchscreen pointer would stay always hidden.**

### Solution 1 (doesn't work):

Using `xicursorset` as suggested by the [above answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129353/235491). The code ultimately uses `XIDefineCursor` to set the cursor image for individual pointers. This simply did nothing for me under KDE, no errors. If it worked, I would set the cursor to an empty image, which I'm not sure would solve the flickering issue.

### Solution 2 (only partially works):

Leaving the touchscreen floating via:

```
$ xinput float 11
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ My mouse                                  id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
...
∼ My touchscreen                                id=11   [floating slave]
```

In this configuration, no KDE window recognizes the touchscreen but surprisingly, Chrome recognizes gestures like one finger scroll or two finger pinch zoom. If I could get this kind of functionality in every window, it would be enough for me.

### Solution 3 (works in theory, not in practice due to crash):

To add/remove pointer dynamically. In other words, using the following script called `~/.local/bin/watch-touchscreen.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys;
from subprocess import call;
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if line.startswith("button press"):
        call(["xinput", "create-master", "Touchscreen"])
        call(["xinput", "reattach", "11", "Touchscreen pointer"])
    elif line.startswith("button release"):
        call(["xinput", "remove-master", "Touchscreen pointer"])
```

like this:

```
$ xinput test 11 | ~/.local/bin/watch-touchscreen.py
```

The idea is to create a new pointer every time the touchscreen is touched and destroy it when the touch is released, at which point the touchscreen would return to being a floating slave. This works very briefly until the X session promptly crashes, forcing me to login again. Not a clever idea to dynamically create and destroy xinput pointers after all, I guess.

Any ideas, workarounds?