# Linux touchscreen - touch indicator

Tags: debian, touch

Is there any package that adds a touch indicator similar to what is in windows 10/11. I mean such a gray circle that shows where you touch on the screen.

Comment: That's also what I am looking for. On Windows 10/11, it is called 'Visual Feedback'. For me, the finger traces are most relevant. You can only assign touch inputs to a separate touch cursor (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129339/touchscreen-and-mouse-as-separate-inputs). Any help is appreciated.